# How to prevent showing "Index" in mvc url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I use ActionLink in my MVC4 website as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("home", result: MVC.Home.Index())
```

after redirect, the url comes in the "www.mysite.com/home/index" form.

How can I prevent showing "home/index" or "index" in url??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing index in url because html.actionlink generates  tag with href home/index. Instead of using helper html.actionlink use  tag directly with href as home and have a default route which routes to index. But in this case you might loose the ability to route correctly when deployed in virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply defaults to the corresponding route in your route configuration like so:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```